# Days count stop at zero

Tags: javascript, countdown

I want to do some countdown exercise https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbmVRYZ_AwE I did a different work by watching this video
I want the countdown to stop at zero but I couldn't. maybe you can help?

```js
var countDate = new Date('02,05,2021 00:00:00:00').getTime();

function newcampaign() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  gap = countDate - now;
  var saniye = 1000;
  var dakika = saniye * 60;
  var saat = dakika * 60;
  var gun = saat * 24;

  var d = Math.floor(gap / (gun));
  var h = Math.floor((gap % (gun)) / (saat));
  var m = Math.floor((gap % (saat)) / (dakika));
  var s = Math.floor((gap % (dakika)) / (saniye));

  document.getElementById('gun').innerText = d
  document.getElementById('saat').innerText = h
  document.getElementById('dakika').innerText = m
  document.getElementById('saniye').innerText = s
}



setInterval(function() {
  newcampaign()

}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2><span>SSD Disk</span>KAMPANYA!<br>Geri Sayım</h2>
  <div class="countdown">
    <div id="gun">00</div>
    <div id="saat">00</div>
    <div id="dakika">00</div>
    <div id="saniye">00</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop it like this. (Selam olsun hehehe)

```
<div class="container">
    <h2><span>SSD Disk</span>KAMPANYA!<br>Geri Sayım</h2>
    <div class="countdown">
        <div id="gun">00</div>
        <div id="saat">00</div>
        <div id="dakika">00</div>
        <div id="saniye">00</div>
        
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var countDate = new Date('02,06,2021 01:00:00:00').getTime();
    
    function newcampaign(interval){
        var now= new Date().getTime();
            gap=countDate - now;
            if(gap <= 0){
              gap = 0;
              clearInterval(interval)
            }
            var saniye=1000;
            var dakika=saniye*60;
            var saat=dakika*60;
            var gun=saat*24;

            var d = Math.floor(gap / (gun));
            var h = Math.floor((gap % (gun))/(saat));
            var m = Math.floor((gap % (saat))/(dakika));
            var s = Math.floor((gap % (dakika))/(saniye));

            document.getElementById('gun').innerText=d
            document.getElementById('saat').innerText=h
            document.getElementById('dakika').innerText=m
            document.getElementById('saniye').innerText=s
          }
         var interval = setInterval(function(){
               newcampaign(interval)
          },1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i propose

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("feb 6, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```